# Parallel processing and auto scaling in spring-kafka KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, autoscaling

I'm using spring-kafka to consume messages from two Kafka topics, which sends same message format as below.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"topic_country1", "topic_country2"}, groupId = KafkaUtils.MESSAGE_GROUP)
    public void onCustomerMessage(String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
        log.info("Message : {}  is received", message);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

- Can KafkaListener allocate the number of consumer threads according to the number of topics that it listens by it's own and parallel process messages in two topics? Or it doesn't support parallel processing and messages have to wait in the topic till one message gets processed?
- In case if the number of messages in the topic is higher, I need to autoscale my micro-service to start new instances (till the number of partitions). What are the parameters (CPU, memory) I can depend on to find out the number of messages in the topics is higher from KafkaListener point of view? (i.e In an API I can auto-scale the service by monitoring the HTTP latency)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `concurrency` property to run more threads; but each partition can only be processed by one thread. To increase concurrency you must increase the number of partitions in each topic. When listening to multiple topics in the same listener, if those topics only have one partition, you may not get the concurrency you desire unless you change the kafka consumer partition assignor.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer

> When listening to multiple topics, the default partition distribution may not be what you expect. For example, if you have three topics with five partitions each and you want to use concurrency=15, you see only five active consumers, each assigned one partition from each topic, with the other 10 consumers being idle. This is because the default Kafka PartitionAssignor is the RangeAssignor (see its Javadoc). For this scenario, you may want to consider using the RoundRobinAssignor instead, which distributes the partitions across all of the consumers. Then, each consumer is assigned one topic or partition. ...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. If I set the concurrency level to 15 and run two instances listeners of the second instance will be idle? Instated of creating new threads to assign to partitions my requirement is to assign to the topic. i.e if @KafkaListener listens to two partitions there should be two threads to consume parallel. Is it possible?  Also what are the parameters that can be considered to measure high message volume for auto scaling?

Comment: I created 2 topics with 6 partitions in each and listen to topics using same listener with concurrency = 2. In this case, even though the listener creates two threads assignment of that threads are random among the partitions in both groups. The thread will not be assigned based on the topic.

Comment: You can either implement your own `PartitionAssignor` or simply add two `@KafkaListener` annotations to the method, with each one getting one topic; then you will get your desired distribution.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to scale horizontal beyond the partition count and dynamically - consider using something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC). It can be used within a Spring context.

By using PC, you can processing all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes to process, and you can be as concurrent as you wish - and this can scale dynamically.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).

Comment: I have done a POC on Parallel Consumer and the results are astounding. Could you please help me how we can implement this using Java Spring Boot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my answer?